# Jquery UI Multiple Datepicker selection

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi I have several date pickers all under the same class of `.datepicker` I have a function which executes `onSelect` of any of the date pickers. However I want to execute another function on selection of a specific date picker I've tried to do a separate date picker assignment to the specific one I want a separate function on but can't seem to get it to work

Original Datepicker Class

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({

            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onSelect: function (date_check) { }

})
```

My specific targeted date picker which also holds class of datepicker.

```
$("#myDate").datepicker({

                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                onSelect: function (date_assign) { }

    })
```

**My question is:**

Is there a way I can target specific datepickers with the `.datepicker` class to perform a secondary onSelect function to that specific datepicker. Or is there a different way?

*NB The datepicker has to be able to perform both the original function under the `.datepicker` class and the new function.

**UPDATE**

```
<input class="datepicker" id="a"> </input>
<input class="datepicker" id="b"> </input>
<input class="datepicker" id="myDate"> </input>
```

On selection of a or b or myDate run the the original `.datepicker` `onSelect` function

On selection of specifically myDate run the original `.datepicker` `onSelect` and run a separate onSelect function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom event then trigger that, passing the parameters from the select to the custom event:

```
$('#myDate').on('customevent', function(e, dateText, inst) {
  alert('custom triggered' + dateText);
});
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  showButtonPanel: true,
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    if ($(this).is('#myDate')) {
      $('#myDate').trigger("customevent", [dateText, inst]);
    }
    // do universal code
    alert('Date:' + dateText);
  }
});
```

Play around with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/3grqL8c9/

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the option `onSelect` is already been assigned and if so add it to the function like so

```
var onSelectFn = $("#myDate").datepicker( "option", "onSelect")
$("#myDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                onSelect: function (date_assign) { 
                     if(typeof onSelectFn === 'function') onSelectFn();
                     // do the next function
                }

    })
```

**UPDATE**

in order to updated the `onSelect` property of the `#myDate` selector you need to work like this

first `datePicker` all of the `.datepicker` element like so

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                showButtonPanel: true,
                onSelect: function (date_assign) { 
                     if(typeof onSelectFn === 'function') onSelectFn();
                     // do the next function
                }

    })
```

then update the `onSelect` of the `#myDate`

```
$("#myDate").datepicker( "option", "onSelect",function(data_assign){
  // your new functionality 
})
```

that should do the trick :)

Comment: Sorry, will this only run the second function if the "#myDate" element is "selected" ?

Comment: no its will run them both, you want to disable the first and run the other?

Comment: Okay, but I only want to run the second function when the "#myDate" datepicker is selected. I'll try to provide and example in my question. Check out my update, see if that explains what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do what I want it to do. Selecting any date picker works in executing its function. However selecting the #myDate date picker does not execute the second function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onSelect: function (date_check) {

            //DO SOME FUNCTION STUFF

           if($(this).attr('id') == "myDate") {

            //DO SOME EXTRA STUFF

           }
      }
});
```

**How it works**

Every datepicker uses the `.datepicker` class and performs the first function, but when you click the `#myDate` datepicker it gets the id attribute for `$(this)` which according to the jquery UI Datepicker API:

onSelect Function

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the
>   selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters.
>   `this` refers to the associated input field.

So `this` gets you the current clicked datepicker. Then you can perform a comparison on the ID to the element you want it to match and then do your second bit of function.